# how to get pixel coordinates from position pass?

Tags: python

I'm trying to get pixel coordinates from position pass, namely the world coordinate. Currently my solution is to render with position pass as OpenEXR output and get camera intrinsic and external matrix with python script. Then with the projection matrix, Zc[x, y, 1]^T = M(R[X_w, Y_w, Z_w]^T + T), it should be able to get [x, y] (pixel coordinates) from world coordinates (X_w, Y_w, Z_w). The code for parsing position pass OpenEXR and getting intrinsic and external matrix are as below.

```py
import numpy as np
import Imath
import OpenEXR
import array

def parseBlenderExr(exr_path, h, w, exr_type='flow'):
    file = OpenEXR.InputFile(exr_path)
    FLOAT = Imath.PixelType(Imath.PixelType.FLOAT)
    if exr_type == 'flow':
        flow_bwd, flow_fwd = np.zeros((h, w, 2)), None
        (R,G) = [array.array('f', file.channel(Chan, FLOAT)).tolist() for Chan in ("R", "G") ]
        flow_bwd[:,:,0] = np.array(R).reshape(h,w)
        flow_bwd[:,:,1] = -np.array(G).reshape(h,w)
        if 'A' in file.header()['channels']:
            (B,A) = [array.array('f', file.channel(Chan, FLOAT)).tolist() for Chan in ("B","A") ]
            flow_fwd = np.zeros((h, w, 2))
            flow_fwd[:,:,0] = -np.array(B).reshape(h, w)
            flow_fwd[:,:,1] = np.array(A).reshape(h, w)
        
        return flow_bwd, flow_fwd
    elif exr_type == 'depth':
        depth = np.zeros((h, w))
        R = array.array('f', file.channel('R', FLOAT)).tolist()
        depth = np.array(R).reshape(h,w)
        return depth
    elif exr_type in ['position', 'segment']:
        target = np.zeros((h, w, 3))
        (R,G,B) = [array.array('f', file.channel(Chan, FLOAT)).tolist() for Chan in ("R", "G", "B") ]
        target[:,:,0] = np.array(R).reshape(h,w)
        target[:,:,1] = np.array(G).reshape(h,w)
        target[:,:,2] = np.array(B).reshape(h,w)
        return target
    else:
        raise NotImplementedError()
```

```py
import numpy as np
import bpy
import os

workpath = "xxx"
external_matrix = bpy.data.objects['Camera'].matrix_world
np.save(os.path.join(workpath, "external_matrix.npy"), external_matrix)

scene = bpy.context.scene

scale = scene.render.resolution_percentage / 100
width = scene.render.resolution_x * scale # px
height = scene.render.resolution_y * scale # px

camdata = scene.camera.data
aspect_ratio = width / height
intrinsic_matrix = np.zeros((3,3), dtype=np.float32)
intrinsic_matrix[0][0] = width / 2 / np.tan(camdata.angle / 2)
intrinsic_matrix[1][1] = height / 2. / np.tan(camdata.angle / 2) * aspect_ratio
intrinsic_matrix[0][2] = width / 2.
intrinsic_matrix[1][2] = height / 2.
intrinsic_matrix[2][2] = 1.
intrinsic_matrix.transpose()
np.save(os.path.join(workpath, "intrinsic_matrix.npy"), intrinsic_matrix)
```

However, I found this solution not work currently even with the default "general" scene. Below is a small test. The pixel coordinate of vertex at approximately [1, -1, 1] turns to be completely wrong! Am I doing something wrong? [image]

Comment: Oops, I found that the problem is the external_matrix got from `bpy.data.objects['Camera'].matrix_world` should be inverted before passing to projection equation. And this should avoid the problem above.